# Are all quotients of a weakly contractible space via a free group action classifying spaces of the group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

First of all, I don't want to restrict to any kind of "nice spaces" since I am interested in the most general situation. Especially I do not work in any "convenient" category of spaces.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space) defines a classifying space of a topological group $G$ as the quotient space of a weakly contractible space $EG$ with respect to a free action of $G$ on $EG$.

For me, a classifying space $BG$ should be a space for which there exists a principal $G$-bundle $$G\rightarrow EG\rightarrow BG,$$ such that for sufficiently nice spaces $X$ the homotopy classes from $X$ to $BG$ are in bijection (via pullback of the bundle $EG\rightarrow BG$) to the set of isomorphism classes of principles $G$-bundles on $X$. I think it was Milnor (Can you give me a reference?) that showed that universality of the bundle $EG\rightarrow BG$ is equivalent to the (weak?) contractibility of $EG$.

From this viewpoint the definition of wikipedia suggests, that the quotient map of any weakly contractible space to the quotient via a free group action of $G$ is a principle $G$-bundle. This sounds strange to me as I would except, that I will need more topological restrictions on my spaces that this works.

So here is the question: 
Which are the exact most general topological restrictions to each space, such that the situations I described work out? To be more specific:

1. When is the quotient map of a space with respect to a free action of a topological group $G$ a principal $G$-bundle?
2. Does the definition of wikipedia gives me always the right thing?
3. What is the canonical reference for the claim that a principal $G$-bundle is universal iff it's total space is (weakly?) contractible?
4. Which topological restrictions on $X$ do I need such that $[X,BG]$ classifies what it should classify?

Comment: Your definition of a classifying space is not invariant under weak equivalence. You should instead say "the weak homotopy classes..." which amounts to having the freedom to CW replace $X$ or $BG$ as necessary.